# Cannot find the `flutter.plugin.platforms` key in the `pubspec.yaml`

Tags: android, flutter

[After hitting pub get, we are getting this "Cannot find the `flutter.plugin.platforms` key in the `pubspec.yaml`" error, after reinstalling the android studio we are getting this error for the same project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ExGf.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have installed flutter and dart plugin in android studio since you have reinstalled android studio you might have missed this step.
2. Sometimes few files might be corrupted you can try `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` to fix it.

If none of the steps helped please provide the `flutter doctor -v` output in the question.

Comment: There are some packages added in pubspec.yaml which versions are not supported, i added some packages with different supported versions and problem is solved.